# Spring REST Security : Enable Basic Authentication only on a specific endpoint

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-restcontroller

I have configured Spring Security for my REST API (with HeaderHttpSessionStrategy).

My 'WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter' implementation looks as below.

```
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http

            .csrf().disable()

            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/user/**").authenticated()
                .antMatchers("/**").permitAll()

                .and()
            .requestCache()
                .requestCache(new NullRequestCache())
                .and()

            .httpBasic()
            ;

    }
```

Now, how can I configure 'HttpSecurity' object so that the basic authentication is only possible with a specific endpoint.

For example:

**/user/login** : Basic Authentication should only be possible on this end point.After sucessfull authentication x-auth-token header is returned.

**/user/create** : Client should not be able to authenticate on this endpoint.Should only return 401.Can only be accessed using the 'x-auth-token' created using /user/login endpoint.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can define multiple `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`s. One of higher priority which has a request matcher to restrict applicability to `/user/login` like: `http.requestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/user/login"))`, and another one as a catch-all for the rest. You can omit the `requestMatcher` to make the http definition unrestricted.

Answer (score 1):

You must always define restrictions from specific to generic. In your case it should be specific URL checks to generic security checks.

1. You should configure and permit signin / signup URLs.
2. You should avoid pattern /** to permit all. instead configure static resource URL separately.
3. You should finally apply more generic restriction like you mentioned on URL, /user/** to be authenticated and having some roles.

   ```
     @Override
     protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

   http
   .csrf().disable()
   .authorizeRequests()
   .antMatchers("/user/login, /user/signup, /logout").permitAll()
   .antMatchers("/user/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
   .and()
   .requestCache()
   .requestCache(new NullRequestCache())
   .and()

       .httpBasic();
   ```

   }